# Mapping problem

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

**I am Using Solidity compiler 0.4.11 When I compile my code i get the error that is " Error: Type "mapping(string => string)" not supported for state variable.\n\tmapping (string => string) dataLink **.

My code is ....

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract HDataAccessManager {

    mapping (string => string) dataLink;
    mapping (string => string) dataHash;
    mapping (string => bytes32) private passwords; 
    string[] users;


    function _isValid(string _user_id, string _encryption_key_hash) returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0;i<users.length;i++){
            if(keccak256(users[i]) == keccak256(_user_id) && 
                keccak256(_encryption_key_hash) == passwords[_user_id]) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function addUser(string _user_id, string _encryption_key_hash) {
        users.push(_user_id);
        passwords[_user_id] = keccak256(_encryption_key_hash);
    }

    function totalUsers() returns (uint) {
        return users.length;
    }


    // link is alias of generated_id
    function storeLink(string _user_id, string _link){

        // check if user is present in blockchain
        //require(_isValid(_user_id, _encryption_key_hash));

        dataLink[_user_id] = _link;
    }

    function storeHash(string _user_id, string _hash){

        // check if user is present in blockchain
        //require(_isValid(_user_id, _encryption_key_hash));

        dataHash[_user_id] = _hash;
    }


    function retrieveLink(string _user_id, string _encryption_key_hash) returns (string, string) {

        //check if user is present in blockchain
        require(_isValid(_user_id, _encryption_key_hash));

        string link = dataLink[_user_id];
        string hash = dataHash[_user_id];
        return (link, hash);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using version:0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.Emscripten.clang or superior this code compiles well. Note that you are using a very old version of solidity, using Remix has the advantage of giving you the latest releases of solidity.

Hope this helps

Comment: if the code is write why giving the error .. new version also the same problem

Comment: when using new version 0.5.0 gives this error             "{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}' "

Comment: where are you compiling this? I just copied the code to remix and it worked with described above, let me know

Comment: i am compiling this on terminal  like this "   $ node > code = fs.readFileSync('HealthcareContract.sol').toString()  > solc = require('solc')
>compiledCode = solc.compile(code)     "   then getting the error

Comment: i install the compiler off solidity in terminal by "sudo npm install solidity@0.4.11"  can you please check this on terminal

Comment: sir please can you update it its my project work and i am stuck ed here

Comment: The problem is that your code has no errors, is your compiler setting which seems to be wrong. Even with 0.4.11 it compiles well in remix.

Comment: can you please tell me the steps where and how are you running this code perfectly

Comment: https://remix.ethereum.org, just copy and paste your code in there, then click on compile

Comment: sir  as you say i  am doing but getting so much error i shared image in answer will you check

Comment: you need to change the compiler in trhe compile tab to match the version in your smart contract

Comment: can you check this in terminal.